# How to compensate Vbe temperature dependancy

Tags: transistors, temperature

The circuit above is used to detect an event at a certain input voltage. Nevertheless according to the temperature, the event is not detected at the same temperature as the VBE(ON) changes with the temperature.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to compensate this circuit against temperature change ?

Comment: That's a terrible circuit if you need accuracy, especially for something going into production.  Use a comparator and a reference. (Or a TL431 as Neil suggests.)

Comment: Jess, using a BJT (whose Vbe varies about -2 mV/K) as a comparator isn't sensible. If you make a comparator out of a differental pair (especially if you get the BJTs for it from a package that has both BJTs on the same die) then this is much better. You still need a reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest approximate way to compensate a transistor VBE is to place another diode, or better still a diode connected 2N2222, in series with R1. Unfortunately, that also cancels the 'reference' element of VBE that you are using.

Instead, consider using a TL431 or TLV431, using its adj terminal as the 'base', and it will behave like an NPN transistor, with a temperature stable 'VBE' of 1.25 V for the TLV431, or 2.5 V for the TL431.

The classic way is to use a temperature stable reference voltage into one terminal of a comparator.

Comment: For the TL431, do you mean equivalent 'VBE' of 2.5V?

Comment: @SimonFitch Thanks for catching that. I was typing TLV431 without paying much attention, and obviously missed hitting the V properly. Now fixed.

Answer (score 7):

You are using the Vbe as a reference, so cancelling it out won't do you much good.

An IC comparator with a reference, either divided from the power supply if that's good enough for you, or an IC reference, is one good solution.

Here's a simple discrete circuit that improves the temperature sensitivity by about 6:1 by adding a differential pair and using the power supply voltage as a reference:

[image]